# Filter not being applied

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to apply the filter style to an image. I'm using jQuery mobile, but theoretically this particular item should be out of jQuery Mobile styling.

My CSS:

```
#down-arrow {
        filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
    // Browser Specific
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
    -moz-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
    -o-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
    -ms-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
}
```

And my image in Javascript:

```
                    var downArrowDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    var downArrow = document.createElement("input");
                    downArrow.setAttribute("src", "arrow.png");
                    downArrow.setAttribute("type", "image");
                    downArrow.setAttribute("class", "arrow");
                    downArrow.setAttribute("data-enhance", "false");
                    downArrow.setAttribute("data-role", "none");
                    downArrow.setAttribute("id", "down-arrow");
                    downArrow.setAttribute("onclick", "downVote()");
```

However, the item created is NOT color-shifted, and Chrome is showing my filter style as being overridden.

I check my computed styles, and it says, "filter: none;", in my inherited styles.

Where is this coming from? How is it being set? Why can't I override it? Shouldn't #down-arrow override everything?

Comment: slightly unrelated: the standard property declaration should come after the vendor-prefixed ones, not before, so it can override them when/if needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I'll fix it.

Comment: You are using an ID. That is specific for only and only 1 element. Use a class.

Comment: I only want to use it for one element.

Comment: seems to be working here though http://jsbin.com/rovoja/2/edit

Comment: Exactly, so I'm wondering why it wouldn't be

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel that's not correct. CSS doesn't care about it: http://jsfiddle.net/xbgba80z/ - it's html specification to have unique IDs.

Comment: And besides that, I only want it to apply to 1 and only 1 element. It will ONLY be used on this one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have [unacceptable comments syntax in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments). Remove that `//` and replace with `/* */` and its working fine

```js
var downArrowDiv = document.createElement("div");
var downArrow = document.createElement("input");
downArrow.setAttribute("src", "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3718/Test_Form_6.jpeg");
downArrow.setAttribute("type", "image");
downArrow.setAttribute("class", "arrow");
downArrow.setAttribute("data-enhance", "false");
downArrow.setAttribute("data-role", "none");
downArrow.setAttribute("id", "down-arrow");
downArrow.setAttribute("onclick", "downVote()");
downArrowDiv.setAttribute('class', 'divc');
downArrowDiv.appendChild(downArrow);
document.body.appendChild(downArrowDiv);
```

```css
#down-arrow {
    filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
    -moz-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
    -o-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
    -ms-filter: hue-rotate(240deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3718/Test_Form_6.jpeg">
```

Comment: Doh. Copied an example and didn't even think about that. I'm not a designer. Thanks for pointing out my dunderheadedness.